# cannot use syntax dependent: destroy in place of :dependent => :destroy in rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I thought this syntax

```
whatever: whatever
```

replaces the old one that uses the tASSOC.  However when I try to use it in my model like so

```
dependent: destroy
```

it doesn't work.  Why is this the case?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a symbol as the value it needs to be `dependent: :destroy`

Comment: thanks brad, for some reason I assumed it didn't require the colon in the front of the symbol and I couldn't find the answer on google (because it was such a poor assumption) even though it was staring me in the face in my scaffold generated code